# Convert date from jquery in DateTime

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, datepicker

I use the jquery ui controls.
I have a datepicker and I retrieve the date as follows:

```
var sDate = $("#startDatePicker").datepicker('getDate'); 
var eDate = $("#endDatePicker").datepicker('getDate');
```

which as an example for sDate returns

```
Tue Aug 14 00:00:00 UTC+0200 2012
```

I call the code from the web page as follows

```
$.ajax(
{
  url: '@Url.Action("LogsView","Home")',
  type: 'POST',
  data: { startDate: sDate, endDate: eDate },
  success: function(result) { alert(result); },                        
  error: function(param1) { alert(param1); }
});
```

I have a controller with the following action

```
public JsonResult LogsView(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{   
  var items = FetchItems(startDate, endDate);
  return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

When I run it, part of the error that is returned is as follows (when vied in fiddler):

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'startDate' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult LogsView(System.DateTime, System.DateTime)' ..
```

I've check my params sent via fiddler and it is as follows `startDate=&endDate=`

Anyone know how to format and pass in the date correctly (I assume this is where the error lies)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to add `.toJSON()` to `$("#startDatePicker").datepicker('getDate')`
i.e.  `$("#startDatePicker").datepicker('getDate').toJSON()`

if you get an error on the `toJSON()` function then try

```
var sd = $("#startDatePicker").datepicker('getDate');
var sDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-MM-yy', sd);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the date to string before you send it off to $.ajax() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can this method to convert date to string:

```
function ShowUTCDate()
{
    var dNow = new Date();
    var utc = new Date(dNow.getTime() + dNow.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    var utcdate= (utc.getMonth()+1) + '/' + utc.getDate() + '/' + utc.getFullYear() + ' ' + utc.getHours() + ':' + utc.getMinutes();
    return utcdate;
}
```